# How do I manipulate this trig function in the correct way?

Tags: trigonometry

Alright, so I've been at this question for a while and can't seem to get to the required answer. I don't know if there's some identity that I'm missing or if I'm just being dumb, but I've decided to try and get some help on here with it. Here's the question:

Show that

$$
\frac{\sec^2(x)-2}{\cos(x)+\sin(x)} = \sec(x)(\tan(x)-1)
$$

I would really appreciate some help with this - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{\sec^2(x)-2}{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}
&= \frac{1+\tan^2(x)-2}{\cos(x)+\sin(x)} \\[4pt]
&= \frac{\tan^2(x)-1}{\cos(x)+\sin(x)} \\[4pt]
&= \frac{(\tan(x)+1)(\tan(x)-1)}{\cos(x)+\sin(x)} \\[4pt]
&= \frac{(\tan(x)+1)(\tan(x)-1)}{\cos(x)(1+\tan(x))} \\[4pt]
&= \frac{\tan(x)-1}{\cos(x)} \\[4pt]
&= \sec(x)(\tan(x)-1)
\end{align}

Comment: Argh! Thanks so much for your contribution, really appreciate it. I always seem to get caught off guard with using the difference of two squares and didn't notice it in this question.

Comment: I've edited to use "align" to make things a little prettier; by all means roll back if you prefer your version. Also: at the third-to-last line, where you cancel $1  + \tan x$, you should probably note that this equality only holds where $\tan x \ne -1$ (although lots of folks showing trig identities don't do so!).

Comment: Thanks @JohnHughes, I didn't actually know how to use "align".

Comment: Glad to have been of service (and shown you something new). I wish that "align" didn't make the fonts so large, as sequences of fractions like these don't look great, but ... you get what you pay for. ;)

Comment: @JohnHughes "...you should probably note...".  It could be argued that this qualification is unnecessary, since $\tan x = -1$ implies that $\cos (x) + \sin (x) = 0$ which directly implies that the original identity does not hold.

Comment: @JohnHughes Within MathJax I usually add some vertical space between such displays and I find ``\\[4pt]`` is quite good. You can try with `\tfrac` instead of `\frac`, but the result is not pretty, in my opinion.

Comment: @user2661923: agreed. Do you think that the OP noticed that? :)

Comment: @egreg: As usual, I've learned something new about LaTeX/MathJax from you; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The left-hand side of your equation is given by
$$\frac{1-2\cos^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)(\sin(x)+\cos(x))}$$and the right-hand side:
$$\frac{\sin(x)-\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)}$$ Now use that
$$(\sin(x)-\cos(x))(\sin(x)+\cos(x))=1-2\cos^2(x)$$

Comment: Yep, it seems like there are multiple ways to solve the problem (as always!) - thanks for your contribution! Seems like a really nice way to solve it.

Comment: @Sonnhard: There was a typo in your second expression. I adjusted this.